# LINQ Weirdness with joining tables

Tags: linq

I have to join multiple tables.  The tables have similar data for each table.

```
ID
(table id for FK)
Name
Description
Owner

from d in Departments
join f in Functions on d.DepartmentID equals f.DepartmentID
join pg in Processes on f.FunctionID equals pg.FunctionID
select new { d.DepartmentID, f.Name, pg.Name }
```

This throws an error 'An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name'

is there a better way to join these tables?

Should I do `Select new { d, f, pg }` ?  Is it easy to grab the data from that?

I am very new to LINQ so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler creates the properties of the anonymous type based on the property you use. In your case you use the property `Name` twice. Once in `f.Name` and once in `pg.Name`.
To fix it you have to specify at least one of the two property names explicitly:

```
select new { d.DepartmentID, FunctionName = f.Name, ProcessName = pg.Name }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to give unique names for the two `Name` properties. Something like:

```
from d in Departments
join f in Functions on d.DepartmentID equals f.DepartmentID
join pg in Processes on f.FunctionID equals pg.FunctionID
select new { d.DepartmentID, FName = f.Name, PGName = pg.Name }
```

When you don't specify your own names, the compiler will just use the full name of the property, but since in this case they are both just `Name`, it will generate an error.